# Is a regular Galois extension of constant Galois extension Galois?

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, algebraic-curves

Let $V, W$ be two (smooth, irreducible) varieties defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ be a morphism defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose there is a number field $K$, which is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $\phi$ is a regular Galois cover over $K$; i.e. $K(V)/\phi^*(K(W))$ is Galois with $\overline{K} \cap K(V)=K$.

**Question:** Is the extension $K(V)/\phi^*(\mathbb{Q}(W))$ Galois?

This feels like it should be true since it is built out of a constant Galois extension and a regular Galois extension which don't interact and examples suggest this to be true with the Galois group being a semidirect product. I couldn't find any results in the literature though about this mixed case so would be glad of references as well.

As a simple example, one could take $V=W=\mathbb{P}^1$ with $\phi: x \mapsto x^n$; this induces a regular Galois cover over the cyclotomic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ with the Galois group of $K(V)/\phi^*(\mathbb{Q}(W)$ being isomorphic to $C_n \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(C_n)$.

Comment: As reuns explained (+1) this is true if both $K/\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}(V)/\phi^*(\Bbb{Q}(W))$ are Galois. The compositum of two Galois extensions is Galois, and you get the direct product. But in your example $\Bbb{Q}(V)/\phi^*(\Bbb{Q}(W))$ is not Galois?

Comment: I understand that this is just the compositum if $\mathbb{Q}(V)/\phi^*(\mathbb{Q}(W))$ is Galois. However, my setting is where this is not true but it is geometrically Galois (so $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(V)/\phi^*(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(W))$ is Galois) and $K$ is simply a field where this becomes Galois

Comment: So my question is that if $K$ is a constant extension such that the regular extension induced by $\phi$ on the base changes of $V,W$ to $K$ becomes Galois, is that enough to imply the full tower $K(V)/\phi^*(\mathbb{Q}(W))$ is Galois?

Comment: Sorry, I misread it a bit.

Comment: My bad, sorry for the confusion. Interesting question. Please take a look at my answer version 2 @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K(V)/\Bbb{Q}(V)$ and $K(V)/\phi^*(K(W)))$ both Galois implies that the finite extension $K(V)/(\Bbb{Q}(V)\cap \phi^*(K(W)))$ is Galois.

- If also $\overline{K} \cap \Bbb{Q}(V)=\overline{K} \cap \phi^*(\Bbb{Q}(W))$ then $K(V)/\phi^*(\Bbb{Q}(W))=K(V)/(\Bbb{Q}(V)\cap \phi^*(K(W)))$ is Galois.
- But $\overline{K} \cap K(V)=K$ is not enough. Try with $K=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3),\phi^*(\Bbb{Q}(W))=\Bbb{Q}(x)$, $\Bbb{Q}(V)=K(V)=K(x)[y]/(y^2-x^3-x-\zeta_3)$.

  For $K(V)/\phi^*(\Bbb{Q}(W))$ to be Galois we need to find an automorphism $\sigma$ of $K(V)$ fixing $x$ and such that $\sigma(\zeta_3)=\zeta_3^2$. It means that $\sigma(y)$ is a root of $T^2-x^3-x-\zeta_3^2$ ie. $\sigma(K(V))$ is the function field of an elliptic curve with a different $j$-invariant, so it can't be that $\sigma(K(V))=K(V)$.

  $K(V)/\phi^*(K(W))=K(x)[y]/(y^2-x^3-x-\zeta_3)/K(x)$ is Galois because it is a quadratic extension, on the underlying smooth projective curves the covering $[x:y:1]\to [x:1]$ has a few ramified points with $x=0$, and removing them from both curves gives your Galois covering of smooth **affine** varieties.

  The morphism $V\to W$ defined over $\Bbb{Q}$ is obtained from $V:y^2-x^3-x-a=a^2+a+1=yu-1=0\subset \Bbb{A^4}$ and sending $(x,y,a,u)\to x$

Comment: Thanks for your very comprehensive answer! Your first bit seems to imply that for any pair of Galois extensions $K/F$ and $K/E$, then $K/(F \cap E)$ is also Galois which I wasn't aware of - do you have a reference for this?

Comment: When $K/(F\cap E)$ is a finite extension. $Gal(K/F),Gal(K/E)$ are subgroups of $Aut(K)$ and the subfield fixed by $G=\langle Gal(K/F),Gal(K/E)\rangle$ is $F\cap E$ so $G$ is a finite subgroup of $Aut(K)$ and hence $K/(F\cap E)$ is Galois.